# Ansible yum disable_excludes giving error, how to use it correctly for a particular shell command?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, yum

I need to complete one of the kubeadm installation steps which include the following commands on a centos machine

```
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

I need to perform this via an Ansible automation script and I have not been able to figure out which way to correctly implement this step I tried

```
- name: Install these packages - kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet
        - kubeadm
        - kubectl
      state: latest
      disable_excludes: repoid
      disablerepo: kubernetes
      become: yes
      become_user: root
```

And i got the following output :

```
TASK [Install these packages - kubelet kubeadm kubectl] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [k8s-head]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"pkg_mgr": "yum"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Failure talking to yum: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from kubernetes: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.\nhttps://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes"}
fatal: [k8s-node-1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"pkg_mgr": "yum"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Failure talking to yum: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from kubernetes: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.\nhttps://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for kubernetes"}
```

I know I am doing this wrong but I do not understand if I am supposed to use yum.conf file to rectify it or use any other option from the yum module to disable_exclude Kubernetes. I can always use the shell module but I want to keep it as a last resort.

> **EDIT : TRIED INDENTATION**
> **Disclaimer this worked but is not a solution.**
> So i corrected my identation and tried the ansible script as following

```
- name: Install these packages - kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
      disable_excludes: all
      exclude: kubernetes
    vars:
      packages:
        - kubelet
        - kubeadm
        - kubectl
    become: yes
    become_user: root
```

**I still am not sure if that is the correct way to implement the following commands**

```
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

but my packages are getting installed without an error so it does the job that i want it to do for now.

Comment: Did you add the kubernetes repo first like it says here? https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#k8s-install-1

Comment: Does it work outside of ansible?

Comment: I can't tell if you just indented it incorrectly for this question, or for real, but `state:` and the rest of those keys should not be indented under `vars:` or they will be just that -- vars -- and not parameters to the `yum:` module

Comment: @BrianPursley yes i did do that by using the ansible copy module and copying the .repo file from my control machine to the guest machines

Comment: @Rico it does work outside of ansible, i have tried via both shell commands and scripts which are basically doing exactly what is specified by Brian Pursley in the link

Comment: My identation was wrong i fixed it and it seems to be working ill post my answer soon @mdaniel

Answer (score 3):

I solved it like this:

```
- name: Setup for the Kubernetes's Environment
  hosts: kube-master
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Add Kubernetes yum repository
      become: yes
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
      yum_repository:
        name: Kubernetes
        description: Kubernetes Repository
        baseurl: http://yum.kubernetes.io/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
        enabled: yes
        gpgcheck: yes
        gpgkey: 
          - https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
          - https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
    - name: Install kubeadm (RHEL/CentOS)
      become: yes
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
      yum:
        name: kubeadm
        state: present
```